# Computing the subtotal of all items on their property criteria: qty * price

Tags: javascript

I have an array which represent the item purchases of a customer, and computed the items subtotal in this logic:

```
function getSubtotal(arr) {
  let total = 0.00;
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
    total += (i.qty * i.price)
  });
  return total;  // 1274.21
}
```

And yes of course I get the correct result, but is there any efficient way to do this in JavaScript?

```js
let data = [
  {
    name : 'Item 1', qty: 2, price: 15.50 // 31
  },
  {
    name : 'Item 2', qty: 17, price: 25.13 // 427.21
  }, 
  {
    name : 'Item 3', qty: 102, price: 8.00 // 816
  }
];

function getSubtotal(arr) {
  let total = 0.00;
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
    total += (i.qty * i.price)
  });
  return total; // 1274.21
}

document.write(getSubtotal(data));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any efficient way to do this in JavaScript?

<strike>I compared the `for`, `forEach` and `reduce` efficiency using `console.time` utility. And found that `for` is faster among the three for the same `data`. Here's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xqqg2yn7/) to test out this.</strike>

```js
let data = [{
  name: 'Item 1',
  qty: 2,
  price: 15.50 // 31
}, {
  name: 'Item 2',
  qty: 17,
  price: 25.13 // 427.21
}, {
  name: 'Item 3',
  qty: 102,
  price: 8.00 // 816
}];

function getSubtotalReduce(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((total, item) => total + item.qty * item.price, 0.00);
}
console.time('reduce');
console.log(getSubtotalReduce(data));
console.timeEnd('reduce');


function getSubtotal(arr) {
  let total = 0.00;
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
    total += (i.qty * i.price)
  });
  return total; // 1274.21
}

console.time('forEach');
console.log(getSubtotal(data));
console.timeEnd('forEach');

function getTotalFor(data) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    total += data[i].qty * data[i].price;
  }
  return total;
}

console.time('for');
console.log(getTotalFor(data));
console.timeEnd('for');
```

So, I'll recommend to use the simple `for` loop.

```
function getTotal(data) {
  'use strict';

  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    total += data[i].qty * data[i].price;
  }
  return total;
}
```

---

As can be seen from [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/66), `forEach` is faster than `for`. So, your code is already efficient and expressive.

```
function getTotal(arr) {
    'use strict';

    let total = 0.00;
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
        total += (item.qty * item.price);
    });
    return total;
}
```

---

If you want short solution, you can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
arr.reduce((total, item) => total + item.qty * item.price, 0)
```

```js
let data = [{
  name: 'Item 1',
  qty: 2,
  price: 15.50 // 31
}, {
  name: 'Item 2',
  qty: 17,
  price: 25.13 // 427.21
}, {
  name: 'Item 3',
  qty: 102,
  price: 8.00 // 816
}];

function getTotal(arr) {
  'use strict';

  return arr.reduce((total, item) => total + item.qty * item.price, 0);
}

console.log(getTotal(data));
```

Comment: i never thought that for loop is more efficient than any simple and short solution

Comment: -1 for advising based on micro-performance, that is horrible advice

Comment: @blueraja Thanks for commenting. OP asked for efficient solution. For loop is efficient than forEach and easy.

Comment: @Tushar: Beginners will _always_ say they want the most efficient solution _(see: basically every question on this site)_.  I'm not saying a for-loop is bad here, but the purpose of this site is to help people learn how to write good code, and saying _"choose this because it's the fastest"_ does the exact opposite.

Comment: This benchmark seems to consist almost entirely of startup overhead.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You're correct. `forEach` is better to use for iterating over array. I've made changes to answer. Thanks for correcting. :)

Comment: @usr Yes. I checked the time separately for `for`, `forEach` and `reduce` and found that the difference is not that much.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab Please check the updated answer.

Comment: @Tushar got it..

Answer (score 5):

You are computing the sum of an array, with a twist. Use [`Array.reduce()`](//stackoverflow.com/a/14899827/1157100) to compute sums.

Furthermore, if you are going to use the ECMAScript `let` language feature, you should also use [arrow function notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
function subtotal(items) {
    return items.reduce(
        ((total, item) => total + item.qty * item.price),
        0.00
    );
}
```

Better naming would help. "Get" implies that you are retrieving something that already exists, which is not the case here.  Also, `i` has a connotation of being an index counter, which makes its use in your `forEach()` confusing.

Comment: thanks for further explanation it seems that really `i` is confusing for item and index.